# grep for value of keyvaue pair and format

Tags: linux, command-line, awk, grep

When I do the following

```
ps -aef|grep "asdf"
```

I get a list of processes that are running. Each one of my process has the following text in the output:

```
-ProcessName=XXXX
```

I'd like to be able to format the out put so all I get is:

```
The following processes are running:
Process A
Process B
etc..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed(1)`:

```
... | grep "asdf" | sed -e 's:.*-ProcessName=\([^ ]\+\).*:Process \1:'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can format your `ps` output using `-o` eg

```
ps -eo args| awk -F"=" '/asdf/{print $2}'
```